# How to multiply 2 columns and then SUM the results?

Tags: sql, sum

I'm learning SQL and I couldn't find the solution to my problem anywhere on he forums. Anyway, I'm using a www.dofactory.com SQL Sandbox and I've made a query:

```
 select customer.LastName, Product.ProductName, OrderItem.Quantity, Product.UnitPrice, OrderItem.Quantity*Product.UnitPrice AS "Quantity x UnitPrice" 
FROM Customer
    JOIN [Order] ON [Order].CustomerID = Customer.ID
    JOIN OrderItem ON OrderItem.OrderId = [Order].ID
    JOIN Product ON Product.Id = OrderItem.ProductId
    where
    [Order].TotalAmount = (select max([Order].TotalAmount) FROM [Order])
```

And result:

```
LastNam ProductName    Quantity   UnitPrice      Quantity x UnitPrice
Kloss   Côte de Blaye       60      263.50             15810.00
Kloss   Chartreuse verte    80       18.00             1440.00
```

Now I want to SUM the whole Column "Quantity x UnitPrice". What should I do?

Comment: Please tag properly!!!!!  ONLY tag with dbms that you are using.

Comment: SQL is just a language used by many dbms.  Tag which dbms you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know. I'll remember next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `SUM()`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(oi.Quantity * oi.UnitPrice) AS Summary
FROM Customer c JOIN
     [Order] o
     ON o.CustomerID = c.ID JOIN
     OrderItem oi
     ON oi.OrderId = o.ID JOIN
     Product p
     ON p.Id = oi.ProductId
WHERE o.TotalAmount = (select max(o2.TotalAmount) FROM [Order] o2);
```

Note the use of table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL Server (T-SQL). You can use SUM and GROUP BY like so. I've done it in a subquery, which is how I'd approach this sort of thing.

```
select LastName, ProductName, Quantity, UnitPrice, SUM(Summary)
from (
select customer.LastName, Product.ProductName, OrderItem.Quantity, Product.UnitPrice, OrderItem.Quantity*OrderItem.UnitPrice AS Summary, [Order].TotalAmount
FROM Customer
JOIN [Order] ON [Order].CustomerID = Customer.ID
JOIN OrderItem ON OrderItem.OrderId = [Order].ID
JOIN Product ON Product.Id = OrderItem.ProductId
where
[Order].TotalAmount = (select max([Order].TotalAmount) FROM [Order])) x
group by LastName, ProductName, Quantity, UnitPrice
```

Comment: Thanks both of you. I was hoping to have another column called "Summary" that would Contain that sum in a single query but I think it is impossible. Thanks again.